# What justifies interchanging partial derivatives here?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, fluid-dynamics

I am following a text on turbulence by Frisch. Using the summation convention, he writes the Navier-Stokes equations as
$$\partial_t v_i + v_j\partial_j v_i = - \partial_i p + \nu \partial_{jj}v_i\\
\partial_iv_i = 0.$$
where $\nu$ is a constant. He claims that taking the divergence above results in a Poisson equation.

Taking the divergence results in :
$$\partial_i \partial_t v_i + \partial_i v_j\partial_j v_i = -\partial_i \partial_i p + \partial_i \nu \partial_{jj}v_i.$$
Assuming we may interchange partial derivatives, we have
$$\partial_t \partial_i v_i + \partial_i v_j\partial_j v_i = -\partial_i \partial_i p +  \nu \partial_{jj}\partial_iv_i.$$
By the divergence free condition the first and last terms vanish, leaving
$$\partial_i v_j\partial_j v_i = -\partial_i \partial_i p \\ \implies\partial_{ij}(v_iv_j) = -\partial_{ii}p.$$

The question I have now is what justifies interchanging the partial derivatives as we did?

Also as an aside, I am still grasping the summation notation. How can we think of the term $\partial_{ij}(v_iv_j)$? Since the indices are not repeated adjacently, is it not summed?

Comment: If in doubt, always reinstate the explicit summation symbols, and see how things work out and compare the computations so you understand what the author is doing when omitting summations. Next, the interchange of partial derivatives is justified once the functions are smooth enough (this is the basic equality of mixed partials from multivariable calculus). Even if you're working with rougher situations (e.g Sobolev spaces), with some definition-unwinding, it usually reduces to the elementary situation above.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see, thanks. I knew the interchanging of the partial derivatives requires some level of smoothness, but I didn't know how these were established in the context of the NS equations. It seems that this is merely an assumption. However, I am still having some difficulty with the the summation symbols. Since the indices are repeated, is it equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3 \partial_iv_j\partial_jv_i$?

Comment: yes that's what is intended. To really convince yourself, do as I mentioned above. Put summation symbols in the very first equality, and write things out explicitly from the beginning. Your first equation has $\sum_j$ everywhere. After taking divergence, you have $\sum_{i}\sum_j$ everywhere

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you!